# Calculate Percentage of RowTotal instead of GrandTotal in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, percentage

I am new in Power BI, I am trying to calculate the percentage based on the rowTotal instead of GrandTotal. for example - with my dataset in excel -

RAW Data is like -[image]

from these raw data I want the calculation like -
[image]

Comment: If you are creating a matrix then you can enable sub-totals in Power BI

Comment: No, I am creating a bar chart

Answer (score 2):

Very simple problem to be solved and accept the solution if helping:

1. From the original table, create the `Total` measure:

   `Total = SUM(Sheet2[Compliant]) + SUM(Sheet2[Non-Compliant])`
2. Create the `Percentage` measure

   `Percentage = SUM(Sheet2[Compliant]) / (SUM(Sheet2[Compliant]) + SUM(Sheet2[Non-Compliant]))`

**The outcome using table report**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for checking my post. Actually it was not helping me to get my expected result. I have edited my post with raw data..if possible please check it and advise me.

Comment: I have edited the answer to display the result as per your expectation, please check and accept, thanks

Comment: Yes, this was simple and helped me tog et expected result. Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: Welcome, accept the answer for solving your issue :)